# AngularJS - Sharing Data between controllers from json

Tags: json, angularjs, controller, sharing, angular-services

actually I get stucked since several days with following problem. I like to create a small app which loads data from a json file. The app should consist of 3 views !

- Show a list of data
- Edit view for changing current data
- add view to store new data

Now I learned to use a service which provides data to each controller for each view.

But for the time my service works only with generated data within my variable thing.

How Can I change this that my service will provide data from .json file which may be edited and updated with any controller !

Thanks

Here is my code and [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4bUiYZB2AWFOWWuxi69l?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">
<head>
    <title>Angular: Service example</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script>
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);


projectModule.factory('theService', function() {

    return {
        thing : [{"DATE" : "2014","IATA":"DUS","DUTY":"10:12"},
                {"DATE" : "2015","IATA":"MIA","DUTY":"10:12"},
                {"DATE" : "2017","IATA":"JFK","DUTY":"10:12"}]
    };

      /*

  return {
      thing:[function($http) {
        return $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {})
        return response.data;
      }]
    };

    */

});

function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
    $scope.thing = theService.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
    $scope.someThing = theService.thing; 
    $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}

    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="show in thing">
        <p>
        <b>DATE </b>{{show.DATE}}
        <b>IATA </b>{{show.IATA}}
        <b>DUTY </b>{{show.DUTY}}
      </p>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="edit in someThing">
        <p>
        <input ng-model="edit.DATE"/>
        <input ng-model="edit.IATA"/>
        <input ng-model="edit.DUTY"/>
        </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use $http service and return it:

```
getJson: function() {
   return $http.get('data.json')
}
```

Then in your controller you use it like this:

```
service.getJson(function(data) {
  $scope.thing = data;
})
```

To convert object to json you need to use angular.fromJson i angular.toJson

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

After that you do:

```
$http.post('yourjson);
```

to replace your current json (save changes).

You should also redownload it (to have everything in sync) using $http.get as I described above.

I have found an example [example](http://jsbin.com/EvOSAqo/1/edit?html,js,output). I hope it helps.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for - please correct me if I am wrong. Using this function will generate the scope from json each time. If I want to change data with controller two (see my plunker) for example this won't work.

Comment: So it looks like you need some sync mechanism to be notified whenever json is changed. This may require some backend job too. Read about websockets and livereload. You can`t do it in angular.js only.

Comment: Isn't there any possibility to store json data in any object and modify this with angular (add, edit, delete some data) and when finished generating json from this object again ! This would do the job ! but I haven't found any great tutorial yet. Everything works only with simple data generated within the factory =(

Comment: To convert data from json and to json, you can use angular.toJson and angular.fromJson, when you have done your changes you can do $http.post('youjson'); to save your changes to json file, then you have to redwonloaded using $http.get('yourjson') to make sure you keep it in sync.